# Nginx location part not being replaced in proxy_pass when using variable

Tags: nginx

I have a service listening on `myservice.mycompany.local`

We're proxifying request like this

```
server {
  listen 80;
  location /myservice/ {
    proxy_pass http://myservice.mycompany.local/;
  }
}
```

it all works fine requests on `public.mycompany.com/myservice/api/1/ping` are correctly transformed into request to `http://myservice.mycompany.local/api/1/ping` as there is the trailing `/` 
but now if we try to use a variable

```
  server {
  listen 80;
  set $MY_SERVICE             "myservice.mycompany.local";
  location /acm/ {
    proxy_pass http://$MY_SERVICE/;
  }
}
```

the local service will only receive a requests to `/` with the URI part being lost 
I've been able to reproduce this "problem" with several version of nginx

- 1.8.1-1~wheezy
- 1.4.6-1ubuntu3.5

I'm able also to reproduce it locally by replacing the proxified service by a simple `nc -l 127.0.0.2 8080` and using it as the value of my variable, so it really seems to be something happening inside nginx

And this behaviour is not covered in http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass

Answer (score 0):

You may have discovered an undocumented feature, but you can always use a `rewrite ... break` instead of `proxy_pass` aliasing:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    set $MY_SERVICE             "myservice.mycompany.local";
    location /acm {
        rewrite ^/acm(/.*)$ $1 break;
        proxy_pass http://$MY_SERVICE;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, we were also considering a `location ~ ^/service-name(.*)$` trick , that seems to work too, i'm waiting a bit longer if someone has an explanation on what is going on before choosing your answer